# Web push import from another file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having a little problem, I have Web Push settings in one file called WebPush.ts and I want to import it to another file. but I'm getting an error.

**WebPush.ts**

```
import webpush from 'web-push'

export const WebPush = webpush.setVapidDetails(
  `mailto:${process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL}`,
  process.env.PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY!,
  process.env.PRIVATE_VAPID_KEY!
)
```

and in another file I am importing it.

```
import { WebPush } from '../../Services/WebPush'

async somefunction(){

 await WebPush.sendNotification(pushSubscripton, payload)

}
```

I'm getting this **error**:

> Property 'sendNotification' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

But when I do settings in this file where I want to import this I Don't get error. How can I fix this?